# Function pointers that can take functions with const reference or copied parameters

Tags: c++

I have multiple functions that work on some custom container (or std::vector):

```
template <class T> void op1(const My_container<T> &a) { /* do something */ }
template <class T> void op2(My_container<T> a) { /* do something */ }
```

Now, I want have another function

```
template <class T> void apply_op(const My_container<T> &a, void (*op)(My_container<T>)) {
    op(a);
}
```

However, I want apply_op to be able to work with both op1 and op2.

I guess I can either copy it two times. But if the ops had more parameters, and either parameter could be either a pass by value or by const reference, the number of copies would become very large very quickly. Another way would be to write all functions to take const references and copy them inside if necessary, but that involves rewriting all op functions.

But is there a way (template, perhaps?) to get the apply_op to work with both kinds of ops?

Comment: I recommend you take some time to learn about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps consider using [template parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)? Or perhaps make the argument to `op` a template?

Comment: You should try [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm confined to the ancient C++03 standard...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this result by adding second template parameter to `apply_op` - function type:

```
template <class T, class Op> 
void apply_op(const My_container<T> &a, Op op) 
{
    op(a);
}
```

See working example: https://ideone.com/XYrmtq

Comment: Can that be more specific about what op can be? For example, can I make apply_op to call op(a) if op is a function, and a.op() if op is a member function? Normally, I would do that with overloading, but a general templates prevents that.